# freeCodeCamp Card Counting Question (assigning variables)

Tags: javascript

I just started freeCodeCamp's basic JS course and I was running into an issue with the card counting assignment.

Here's what I have:

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch (card){
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break; 
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    count += " Bet";
  } else {
    count += " Hold";
  }
  
  return count;
}
```

And here's a possible solution:

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      count--;
      break;
  }
  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }
}
```

I understand why the possible solution is correct, but I'm struggling to see why my solution is wrong (freeCodeCamp says that it passes no tests). The only difference I'm seeing is that in the recommended code it takes the count and then appends the " Bet" or " Hold" string and returns it, but in mine I change the entire count variable to whatever the count was and then append the " Bet" or " Hold" strings, and then return the count variable (which should now be the count number with bet or hold attached).

If I'm getting it wrong there must be a difference, but I'm struggling to see it.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You code is updating count. Below is basically an example of what your code is doing. Run it and look at the console `let count = 0; count++; count += " Hold"; console.log(count); count++; console.log(count);`

Comment: What tests are being performed?  If the function is invoked more than once, `count` won't be very useful after the first run.  Though JavaScript allows it, in practice it's generally best not to change the types of your variables in the program logic.

Comment: @David Okay, that makes sense. So essentially since the code runs multiple times, it's then trying to do something like "-1 Hold" + 1 on its second (or further) time around and that's giving it grief. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple debugging would show you what your problem is. console.log() is your friend when you are trying to figure out what is going on. So below is one way to use console.log to see what is happening in your code.

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  console.log('card', card, 'start count', count);
  switch (card){
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break; 
  }

  console.log('updated count:', count);
  
  if (count > 0) {
    count += " Bet";
  } else {
    count += " Hold";
  }
  
  console.log('updated count 2:', count);

  
  return count;
}

cc(2);
cc(3);
```

Now with this you can see that you are updating the variable count and adding a string to it.

```
card 2 start count 0. <-- first time through
updated count: 1
updated count 2: 1 Bet
card 3 start count 1 Bet <-- second time through
updated count: NaN
updated count 2: NaN Hold
```

So you have "1 Bet" and you try to increase that by `1` you get NaN since it you are adding one to a string.

The other solution is just returning the bet string and not updating the count.